# Error when using 'make install' command

Tags: command-line, make, error-handling, execute-command, makefile

I am attempting to install the WRF weather software (http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php#STEP7) that requires the installation of certain libraries. I can unpack the zip files, run `configure`, and `make` executes just fine, but when I try `make install`, I get the following error:

```
make  install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4'
Making install in src/mpl
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/{path_to_dir}/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich/lib'
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/{path_to_dir}’: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Makefile:409: install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:893: install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4/src/mpl'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:23607: install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jmaloney1985/Desktop/Programs/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpich-3.0.4'
make: *** [Makefile:23930: install] Error 2
```

Thoughts on this? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello;  welcome to askubuntu!   Your error seems to be this one?                              /usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/{path_to_dir}’: Permission denied   In this case;  wouldn't it be fixed by either, either by creating the directory, or maybe changing some permissions? (How exactly and where I do not know, was long ago I did ubuntu, but can remember a few things)   Note;If someone spotting a error in this comment, I would appreciate if it's pointed out, thank you!  Edit2:  Is it going to be "{path_to_dir}" - and not changed by the user? (customize?)

Comment: First, note that `mpich` is available direct from the Ubuntu repositories - please confirm that you *really* need to build and install it from source. Second, you almost certainly were meant to replace `{path_to_dir}` with an actual valid directory path during the configuration step. Third, if the real `{path_to_dir}` is a system directory (such as `/usr/local` or `/opt`) then you will need to run `make install` with elevated privileges (usually done by using `sudo`)

Comment: I think he probably would want to make it, instead of just installing -  (or @jmaloney1985 did you want to make it, or just install it from the easiest way?)  Sorry I must ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make tries to install your code here:
**/usr/bin/mkdir:**

This space does not belong to you - you're not allowed to create or copy sth. Instead use:

```
sudo make  install-recursive
```

sudo will give you - and make - the right to do so

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: cool, I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer.